# Regex to test string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create regex for javascript to test string contain word like M.C.A or ACA etc.Regex should return true when these words entered like M.C.A, USD etc.
Regex should return false when enter string  in textbox like

```
 .M.C.A
 ..MM
 M..........A
 M.C.A..
```

I can enter any word with dot or without dot but didn't want to enter string in textbox which
1: start with dot 
2: contain more than one dot between each letter
3: not contain any number
4: start with letter only

Comment: Could you give more examples of matching strings?

Comment: Which regexes have you tried?

Comment: This is not a question, just "I want to do X". Except X is a description so vague I wouldn't even know where to start writing code.

Comment: I'm shaking my head. I don't quite know what you are asking. Could you clarify a bit more? What in totality is to be accepted / rejected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question wasn't quite clear, so I assumed you are trying to validate acronyms. One of the following regexes should do what you want.

To allow only a letter followed by a dot (i.e., `M.C.A.`, `U.S.D.`, `A.C.A.`), use this:

```
r = /^([A-Z][.])*$/gi;
```

To allow only letters followed by other letters (i.e., `MCA`, `USD`, `ACA`), use this:

```
r = /^([A-Z])*$/gi;
```

To allow either a letter followed by a dot, or only letters followed by other letters, use this:

```
r = /^([A-Z])*$|^([A-Z][.])*$/gi;
```

If you want letters to be **optionally or arbitrarily** separated by a dot, you'll want this:

```
r = /^([A-Z][.]?)*$/gi;
```

Examples of valid inputs:

- `MCA`
- `M.CA`
- `MC.A`
- `MCA.`
- `M.C.A`
- `MC.A.`
- `M.C.A.`

If you only need to test combinations of `M`, `C`, `A`, and `.`, then adjust the range in the above regexes from `A-Z` to allow only the letters you care about.

I set up a fiddle to play around with and make sure your specific cases are handled: http://jsfiddle.net/eXStp/